# Button Fill Entire Layout Programmatically

Tags: android, layout, button

I have a question for Android developers. I have a layout with a button (developed programmatically, not with xml) and I want the button to fill the entire layout right now but it currently doesn't and I'm not sure why, I thought I had everything set up correctly with the gravity of the button and the layout params but here's what I have. If you can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it! Thanks.

```
LinearLayout bottom = new LinearLayout(this);
bottom.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);  
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.FILL;
bottom.setLayoutParams(params);  

bottom.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

Button eqbttn = new Button(this);
eqbttn.setText("=");
eqbttn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
bottom.addView(eqbttn);
```

Comment: You want it to fill the entire screen horizontally AND vertically?

Comment: are you doing this from an activity class or view class?

Comment: take relative layout instead of linar and  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); do like such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've only applied the `MATCH_PARENT` size to the `LinearLayout`. You need to apply it to the button, too.

```
Button eqbttn = new Button(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams eqparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
eqbttn.setLayoutParams(eqbttn);
eqbttn.setText("=");
eqbttn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
bottom.addView(eqbttn);
```

This will force the button to fill the LAYOUT *both* vertically and horizontally. If you need the layout itself to take up the whole screen, change its `WRAP_CONTENT` to `MATCH_PARENT` as well.

Also, in this case, you do not require the `Gravity.FILL` layout parameter on the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: As an extension to this, there's a definition of addView that takes layout params as a parameter, so you can do bottom.addView(eqbttn, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); and strip out the two lines dealing with creating, storing, and setting the params on the button manually